# open_basedir restrictions, although the path is in PHP's config

Tags: php, nginx

I am running Nginx and I am trying to install postfixAdmin. When I try to go to `setup.php`, 
it says that config.inc.php is missing, although it is there, and the permissions are correct.

The error log shows me this:

`[error] 18493#0: *22 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/webapps/postfixAdmin/config.inc.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/) in /usr/share/webapps/postfixAdmin/common.php on line 62" while reading response header from upstream`

Basically saying that open_basedir is restricting me from accessing `/usr/share/webapps/`, although `/usr/share/webapps/` is in the open_basedir list. I even added `/usr/share/webapps/postfixAdmin` manually, and it still gave me the same error.

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm hitting the same error....

Comment: @PeterFox Not really, no. It randomly started working when I updated my server.

Answer (score 1):

Please beware that php.ini:open_basedir does not follow any sysmlinks. So if you config.ini.php is residing via symlink in /etc/, you have to specify that directory too.